# Existence of a unitary transform $(q,p) \rightarrow (-q, p)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

If $q$ and $p$ are the canonical position and momentum operators of a quantum harmonic oscillator, is there a unitary that transforms $(q,p)$ into $(-q, p)$?

For instance, denoting the annihilation and creation operators as $a^{(\dagger)} = (q \pm i p) / \sqrt{2}$, then
$$
\mathrm{e}^{i \frac{\pi}{2} a^\dagger a} \cdot (q,p) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-i \frac{\pi}{2} a^\dagger a} = (-p, q) \quad \text{and} \quad
\mathrm{e}^{i\pi a^\dagger a} \cdot (q,p) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-i\pi a^\dagger a} = (-q, -p)
$$
Similarly, is there some Hamiltonian $H$ for which
$
\mathrm{e}^{iH} \cdot (q, p) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-iH} = (-q, p)
$, or is there a reason for why this would not be possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the commutator of $q$ and $p$ is $c$-number the unitary transform would preserve it,
\begin{equation*}
[UqU^\dagger,UpU^\dagger]=UiU^\dagger=i
\end{equation*}
But $(q,p)\mapsto(-q,p)$ changes the sign of this commutator. Therefore such unitary transform is impossible.

However if $U$ is antiunitary $UiU^\dagger=-i$ and such transform exists. It is simply $\mathcal{PT}$ - combination of the reflection and time reversal.